# Macros and Visual Basic not enabled in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel-2010

The Macros and Visual Basic Icon is disabled in Excel 2010. How can I Activate it?
I enabled the developer TAB, however the macro and Visual Basic TAB is not enabled. I googled to check if any solutions were available.

Can someone please help me get it activated. Thank you.

Also, I am curious to know the reason behind this.

Comment: Have you tried to google it? [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Office 2010 has it (Visual Basic for Application) installed.

[image: ChangeOffice2010Install]